# Trying to send a file from a C# client to a node.js TCP server

Tags: c#, javascript, node.js, networking, tcp

I have the following code:

C# client:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

        client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 9090);

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Program.ReadFile(@"C:\pub\image.jpg"));

        using (var stream = client.GetStream())
        {
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("File sent.");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string ReadFile(string path)
    {
        string content = string.Empty;

        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return content;
    }
}
```

node.js server:

```
var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket)
{
    var buffer = new Buffer(0, 'binary');

    socket.on('data', function (data)
    {
        buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, new Buffer(data, 'binary')]);
    });

    socket.on("end", function (data)
    {
        fs.writeFile("image.jpg", buffer);
        buffer = new Buffer(0, 'binary');
    });
});

server.listen(9090, '127.0.0.1');
```

This doesn't work. The file always arrives corrupt. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try sending a text file instead so you can see if/how is being corrupted.

Comment: Strangely, it does indeed work with text files. How come textfiles arrive correct but images don't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is on how you are reading the file in C#. If you write back the file to disk from C# you can see how the number of bytes does not match:

```
// This code does not work
// the number of bytes in image2.jpg won't match image.jpg
byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Program.ReadFile(@"C:\pub\image.jpg"));
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\pub\image2.jpg", buffer);
```

Change your read to use the native C# ReadAllBytes instead:

```
// This works 
// the number of bytes in image2.jpg will match image.jpg
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\file.jpg");
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\pub\image2.jpg", buffer);
```

Your Node.js code is correct and works once you send it the correct bytes from C#.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probabbly encoding issue.

I would try to do:

1) in `C#`: `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Program.ReadFile(@"C:\pub\image.jpg")); //EXPLICITLY SPECIFY UTF8 ENCODING`

and

2) in `JS`: `var buffer = new Buffer(0);`

as, according to the node.js [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_str_encoding) :

> Allocates a new buffer containing the given str. encoding defaults to
>   'utf8'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does make sense to get the encoding in line but unfortunately the image still arrives corrupted.

Comment: @prc322: is the quantity of bytes in C# you send is equal what you recieve in node.js?

Comment: @prc322: also, looking on documentation I don't see *concat* method with second parameter, where you pass "binary". Just remove it, leave it like: Buffer.concat([buffer, new Buffer(data)]); See if this helps.

Comment: changing the line to Buffer.concat([buffer, new Buffer(data)]); did "not help", the image is still corrupted. Also, the size of the original image is 48KB, the size of the image I write to the disk on the server side is 82,9KB. Are there any topics I should give a read before trying to conquer things like this?

Comment: @prc322: did yo try to use base64 string rapresentation of image ?